Writing a test method for an async service layer method
I have a repository layer that does a few CRUD operations. I want to write unit tests for the methods in this class to make sure they work as expected etc.
Here is my repository layer:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PhoneBook.Helpers;
using PhoneBook.Interfaces;
using PhoneBook.Models;

public class MessageRepository : IMessageRepository
{
    private readonly PhoneBookContext _phoneBookContext;
    private readonly ModelMapper _modelMapper;

    public MessageRepository(PhoneBookContext phoneBookContext, ModelMapper modelMapper)
    {
        _phoneBookContext = phoneBookContext;
        _modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> GetAllMessages()
    {
        return await _phoneBookContext.Messages.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MessageDto>> GetAllMessagesForUser(Guid phoneBookEntryId)
    {
        var contactEntries = await _phoneBookContext.Messages
            .Where(x => x.PhoneBookEntryId == phoneBookEntryId)
            .ToListAsync();

        return contactEntries.Select(entry => _modelMapper.ConvertMessageToMessageDto(entry)).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<MessageDto> GetAllMessagesForUserWithDetails(Guid phonebookEntryId)
    {
        var contactEntry = await _phoneBookContext.Messages
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MessageId == phonebookEntryId);

        if (contactEntry == null)
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"No contact entry found with ID {phonebookEntryId}.");
        }

        return _modelMapper.ConvertMessageToMessageDto(contactEntry);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendMessage(MessageDto messageDto)
    {
        if (_phoneBookContext.Messages.Any(x => x.MessageId == messageDto.MessageId))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        messageDto.MessageId = guid;

        var entryToSend = _modelMapper.ConvertMessageDtoToMessage(messageDto);
        _phoneBookContext.Messages.Add(entryToSend);
        await _phoneBookContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        var personToSendTo = await _phoneBookContext.PhoneBookEntries
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PhoneBookEntryId == messageDto.PhoneBookEntryId);

        if (personToSendTo != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message sent to {personToSendTo.Firstname} {personToSendTo.Surname}, title is {messageDto.Title}, message is {messageDto.MessageContent}, message type is {messageDto.MessageType}.");
        }

        return true;
    }
}

The models are pretty simple:
public partial class PhoneBookEntry
{
    public Guid PhoneBookEntryId { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Surname { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;
}

The DTO is exactly the same.
I have written test methods for the Get and Create methods, happy path and unhappy. I am now doing the Update method tests but cannot get them to work.
Here is the test I have so far:
[Test]
public async Task UpdateEntry_ExistingEntry_ValidDto_ReturnsTrue()
{
    // Arrange
    var phoneBookEntryId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var existingPhoneBookEntry = new PhoneBookEntry
    {
        PhoneBookEntryId = phoneBookEntryId,
        Firstname = "John",
        Surname = "Doe",
        PhoneNumber = "1234567890"
    };
    _mockContext.Setup(x => x.PhoneBookEntries.FindAsync(phoneBookEntryId)).ReturnsAsync(existingPhoneBookEntry);

    var updatedDto = new PhoneBookDto
    {
        PhoneBookEntryId = phoneBookEntryId,
        FirstName = "Jane",
        Surname = "Smith",
        PhoneNumber = "9876543210"
    };

    // Act
    var result = await _phoneBookRepository.UpdateEntry(updatedDto);

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    _mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(default), Times.Once);
}

I thought the best way to test it was to create a phoneBookEntry -> add it to the list of phoneBookEntries and then create a dto with a few differences, call the update method and verify the saveChangesAsync method has been called, as well as result not being null.
However, when I run this I get the following error:
Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

This is also the same error I have on my Unhappy path test:
public async Task UpdateEntry_NonExistingEntry_ReturnsFalse()
{
    // Arrange
    var phoneBookEntryId = Guid.NewGuid();
    _mockContext.Setup(x => x.PhoneBookEntries.FindAsync(phoneBookEntryId)).ReturnsAsync((PhoneBookEntry)null);

    var updatedDto = new PhoneBookDto
    {
        PhoneBookEntryId = phoneBookEntryId,
        FirstName = "Jane",
        Surname = "Smith",
        PhoneNumber = "9876543210"
    };

    // Act
    var result = await _phoneBookRepository.UpdateEntry(updatedDto);

    // Assert
    Assert.Null(result);
    _mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(default), Times.Never);
}

In setup, I have the following:
    private Mock<PhoneBookContext> _mockContext;
    private Mock<ModelMapper> _mockModelMapper;
    private Mock<ValidatorService> _mockValidatorService;
    private IPhoneBookRepository _phoneBookRepository;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var phoneBookEntry = new PhoneBookEntry { PhoneBookEntryId = Guid.NewGuid() };
        var phoneBookEntries = new List<PhoneBookEntry> { phoneBookEntry };
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<PhoneBookEntry>>();
        mockSet.SetupData(phoneBookEntries.AsQueryable());

        _mockContext = new Mock<PhoneBookContext>();
        _mockContext.Setup(x => x.PhoneBookEntries).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        _mockModelMapper = new Mock<ModelMapper>();
        _mockValidatorService = new Mock<ValidatorService>();

        _phoneBookRepository = new PhoneBookRepository(_mockContext.Object, _mockModelMapper.Object, _mockValidatorService.Object);
    }

I cant figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. Any advice would be appreciated.
